# jQuery addClass Lost after Partial Postback in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asynchronous, updatepanel, postback

I have the following HTML:

```
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanelA" runat="server" > 
            <ContentTemplate>

    <ul class="MailBoxesItems">
        <li>
            <div id="InboxSelection" runat="server" class="MailLinkContent" >
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="UnreadSelection" runat="server" class="MailLinkContent">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="SentSelection" runat="server" class="MailLinkContent">
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

      </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I use the following script to select the div when I click on it:
This script first removes all the "SelectedMail" classes from all the divs and then
adds the "SelectedMail" class to the selected div.

```
    $('.MailBoxesItems li div.MailLinkContent').click(function () {
        $('.MailBoxesItems li div.MailLinkContent').removeClass('SelectedMail');
        $(this).addClass('SelectedMail');
    });
```

Here's the CSS:

```
    .SelectedMail {
        background-color:#f5f5f5;
    }
```

The Problem that after a postback occurs somehow the addClass assignment of jQuery is Lost.

Comment: If you add a class to element 1 and replace element 1 with element 2, element 2 will not have the class that you added to element 1. The addClass assignment is not lost, you are simply replacing the element entirely with a new one that doesn't already have the class.

Comment: @KevinB I'm not following you, If I add only this line to the click event: $(this).addClass('SelectedMail'); It would still have the same effect.

Comment: @Kevin B Note if I change the color of the text using the .css property it would still have the same effect, I don't think my code is wrong, I think it has something to do with partial/postback.

Comment: Think about it this way... If you have a basket of apples and take one out, you have one apple. You take a bite of that apple. If you throw that apple away and get another, the new apple doesn't have a bite taken out of it. That's what is happening here. element 1(the one you added the class to on click) no longer exists, it has been replaced completely by element 2. Element 2 has not been clicked yet, therefore it doesn't have the class yet.

Comment: @Kevin B Thanks for the help what I understood from the beggining is that on each Postback the elements are replaced, I think that's what happened? If so, do you know how can I come up with a solution to this? Thank you.

Comment: Well, it's a logic problem, not really a syntax error. You have to either not replace the element, store it's state and mirror it on the new element, or check it's state before you replace it and apply that state to the new element.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem caused by mixing the conventional ASP.Net Ajax and jQuery events. When you do the partial postback, the DOM is recreated and the jQuery events are lost.

Try registering your jQuery event this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // the event binding is wrapped in a function avoiding code replication
    function bindEvents() {
        $('.MailBoxesItems li div.MailLinkContent').click(function () {
            $('.MailBoxesItems li div.MailLinkContent').removeClass('SelectedMail');
            $(this).addClass('SelectedMail');
        }); 
    }

    // bind the events (jQuery way)
    $(document).ready(function() {
        bindEvents();   
    });

    // attach the event binding function to every partial update
    Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function(evt, args) {
        bindEvents();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: What you did will restore the scripts once they are lost after postback but my problem is that after I assign the class to the div using the addClass function once partial postback occurs the elements are re-created so the class that was assigned is no longer there. I need to find a way to do this.